# Black plasma BPS rig skin glitch

Tags: rigify, rigidbody

I have a problem with the blender BPS rig v2. When I give it a skin the skin is messed up. When I remove all second layers it is ok but then my second layers are gone. I guess the problem is that the skin version is for 1.8 and the BPS is set to 1.7.10 and arbiter made a video about that but it is for the old rig nit for the v2. And in the v2 there are no UV maps for the other version. Can you tell me how to solve the problem?

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem! It was mcprep! The function prep materials made the skin glitch when improve gui wqs activated